# PictureBox select switchnig with arrow keys

Tags: c#, keyboard, picturebox

I need help I have a set PictureBox (40), and I need to select these pictureboxes with arrows. I mean when I'm on the first picture and press right arrow key (border changing - selected), the border of the first should switch to none and next one switch to border FixedSingle.

One idea is:

```
if (keyData == Keys.Right) {
    if (PictureBox1.BorderStyle == BorderStyle.FixedSingle) {
        PictureBox1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
        PictureBox2.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
    } else if (PictureBox2.BorderStyle == BorderStyle.FixedSingle) {
        pictu.....
    }
}
```

but this method takes too much time so I'm looking for a simpler method.

Can somebody help me find a simpler way to do this?

EDIT new code:

```
  namespace testPics
```

{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Form1_KeyDown_1(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        changePictureBox(e.KeyData);
    }
    List<PictureBox> myPictureBoxes;
    int index;
    public void iniPictureBoxes()
    {
        myPictureBoxes = new List<PictureBox>();
        myPictureBoxes.Add(pictureBox1);
        myPictureBoxes.Add(pictureBox2);
        myPictureBoxes.Add(pictureBox3);

        index = 0;
    }

    public void changePictureBox(Keys keyData)
    {
        myPictureBoxes[index].BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;

        if (keyData == Keys.Right)
        {
            if (index < myPictureBoxes.Count - 1)
                index++;
        }
        else if (keyData == Keys.Left)
        {
            if (index > 0)
                index--;
        }
        myPictureBoxes[index].BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
    }}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a list of pictureboxes.
Then for example you can add an indexer (just to keep it simple).
The indexer is an int (or in your case can be a byte) that stores the index of the currently selected picturebox.
If the user presses "right arrow" key just change the border of the current indexed picturebox increment the indexer and update "the now indexd picturebox".

```
    List<PictureBox> myPictureBoxes;
    int index;
    public void iniPictureBoxes()
    {
        myPictureBoxes = new List<PictureBox>();
        myPictureBoxes.Add(pictureBox1);
        myPictureBoxes.Add(pictureBox2);
        index = 0;
    }

    public void changePictureBox(Keys keyData)
    {
        myPictureBoxes[index].BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;

        if(keyData == Keys.Right)
        {
            if(index < myPictureBoxes.Count - 1)
                index++;
        }
        else if(keyData == Keys.Left)
        {
            if(index>0)
                index--;
        }
        myPictureBoxes[index].BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
    }
```

this just sets the borderstyle. If you want to really select the picturebox you also need to implement it (`picturebox.select();`)

It may be better to create the pictureboxes generically. So you don't have to do add all of them manually to the List.

Here is the generic code for adding pictureboxes (in this case 5):

```
public void iniPictureBoxes()
    {
        myPictureBoxes = new List<PictureBox>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            PictureBox tempPB = new PictureBox();
            tempPB.Location = new Point(i * 15, 10);
            tempPB.Size = new Size(10, 10);
            tempPB.BackColor = Color.Black;
            Controls.Add(tempPB);
            myPictureBoxes.Add(tempPB);
        }
            index = 0;
    }
```

and here the way to add an event: just double click the event u want to have.
[image]
Then a method is being auto generated for you. And you should change it to

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        changePictureBox(e.KeyData);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm noob can you please post here a sample code ?

Comment: Thank you, but the code don't work for me, I put this into my code and when I'm pressing arrows it isn't changin and how can I do this generically ?

Comment: How do you get the userinput (keystrokes)? (I tested it and it's working for me)

Comment: The borders don't changing, I really don't know what I'm doing bad. I try new project.

Comment: You need to add an event to your Form that gets the user input.

Comment: ok, i will look for it, how to make user input and then tell you.

Comment: You need to add an event. I used "KeyDown"

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line
Error CS7036 There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'e' of 'Form1.changePictureBox(object, KeyEventArgs, Keys) I got this error

Comment: you need to call the inipictureboxes() method in your Form1 constructor. (Below InitializeComponent();)

Comment: OHH, man working, thank you very much now i understand it :))))), where can i honor you ? :D, I'm so stupid :(

Comment: I upvoted your answer and that tell me thanks for feedback..... and I pressed the tick :)